# Struggling to convert grouped data to a boxplot with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have a data set where the goal is to create a box plot of two grouped columns, and I cannot figure out how to properly code the boxplot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
scooters = pd.read_csv(.......)
df = pd.DataFrame(scooters)
dx = df.groupby("Day of Week")["Trip Duration"]
box_plt = sb.boxplot(data = dx, x = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']);
box_plt.set(xlabel = ['Day of Week'], ylabel = ['Trip Duration'])
box_plt.plot()
plot.show()
```

Currently nothing happens when I run the above code. Every resource is definitely where it's supposed to be, but the goal, which was to group the Trip Durations by each day of the week and then make a box plot for each day, has been incredibly confusing. Any tips would be appreciated for how I can make a plot for each day. When I print the groups they're correctly grouped, as in there's a 0 group for Monday with all those values, 1 for Tuesday, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Some remarks:

- Seaborn does the grouping for you, it even can't create a good boxplot without the original data.
- `pd.read_csv()` already creates a dataframe, you shouldn't convert it a second time to a dataframe. (So, `scooters` in your example is already a dataframe)
- For readability and checking with tutorials, it helps to use the standard abbreviations such as `sns` for `seaborn`
- Seaborn automatically puts the dataframe columns as names for x and y labels.
- `order=` can be used to fix an order on the x-axis. Otherwise, the order comes from the order they appear in the dataframe. (Using `pd.Categorical()` on the dataframe column is another way to set an order.)
- `sns.boxplot` doesn't return a plot, it creates a plot and returns the `ax` on which the boxplot has been drawn.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

days_of_week = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']
scooters = pd.DataFrame({'Day of Week': np.repeat(days_of_week, 200),
                         'Trip Duration': np.abs(np.random.randn(7, 200).cumsum(axis=1)).ravel() * 30 + 20})

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
ax = sns.boxplot(data=scooters, x='Day of Week', y='Trip Duration', order=days_of_week, palette='turbo')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot example]